# write Data to DataRow in DataTable with C#

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable, datarow

I have a DataTables with Emails. Over the LDAP I have the Userdata. Now Id like to Increase the DataTable depending upon the EmailAdress.

```
myDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LDAP_Data"));

foreach(DataRow row in modiTable.Rows)
{
    string myLDAPData = DoLDAPAction(row.Field<string>("EMAIL"));

    //how to insert to myDataTable > LDAP_Data
}
```

how can I insert the new Data from LDAP to the new Column?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the [NewRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
foreach(DataRow row in modiTable.Rows)
{
    string myLDAPData = DoLDAPAction(row.Field<string>("EMAIL"));

    DataRow row = modiTable.NewRow();
    row["EMAIL"] = myLDAPData;
    //You might want to specify other values as well
}
```

Or you can use the [Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yfsd47w(v=vs.110).aspx) method, as suggested in kara's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a row to a `DataTable` you have to add a row which columns match you table. This is why you get back a row if you call `DataTable.Add()`.

Here an example how to add new rows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // Create a example-DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Name", DataType = typeof(string) }); // Add some columns
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Id", DataType = typeof(int) });

    // Let's fill the table with some rows
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) // Add 20 Rows
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add(); // Generate a row
        row["Id"] = i; // Fill in some data to the row. We can access the columns which we added.
        row["Name"] = i.ToString();
    }

    // Let's see what we got.
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) // Loop through all columns
    {
        Console.Write(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + ";"); // Write the ColunName to the console with a ';' a seperator.
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows) // Generic looping through DataTable
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) // Loop through all columns
        {
            Console.Write(r[i] + ";");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation, so newcomers will understand your answer as well. I would like to upvote your answer, but a code-only answer should not be upvoted.

Comment: @LajosArpad okay, okay :o) Added some comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
myDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LDAP_Data"));

foreach(DataRow row in modiTable.Rows)
{
    string myLDAPData = DoLDAPAction(row.Field<string>("EMAIL"));

    var row = myDataTable.NewRow()
    row["LDAP_Data"] = YOUR_DATA;
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```